# Dynamic form based on user select on multiple levels

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony

I would need to create a form based on user input on multiple levels.
Let me explain :

I have a "base" form with a few fields, "Customer" (select) being one of them.
When user selects a customer, it loads a subform. This subform is different for every customer and can hold some conditions beneath it. Let me explain :

```
CustomerA
    --> Display customerA subform
    Input1
    Input2
    Select1
        Yes
        No
        [options can be managed in database]
    Select2
        Yes
            --> Display customerA.select2.option.yes subform
            Input1
            Select1
                Option1
                Option2
                Option3
                [options can be managed in database]
            ...
        No

CustomerB
    Select1
        Option1
        Option2
        [options can be managed in database]
    Select2
        Yes
        No
        [options can be managed in database]
    Input1
    ...
```

I thought about using a json object (Doctrine) to store this. But I can't figure out how to handle the storage of the form fields (parent id ?) and computation of conditions...

I'm a bit lost in all this stuff.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Symfony then you should read the [Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) part of Symfony's documentation.